# React-Native Android Build Failure: Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'. Failed to process resources

Tags: android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, react-native, google-play-services

I cannot figure out what is wrong with the build. I tried the common solutions of running ./gradlew clean as well as adding the android.enableAapt2=false to the gradle.properties.

The google-services.json folder is at the /android/app level.

Im at a loss right now as to how to get past this one.

If I forgot to include something useful please lmk and I will update.

Cheers

Error Output

> Configure project :app
>   WARNING: The specified Android SDK Build Tools version (26.0.1) is ignored, as it is below the minimum supported version (27.0.3) for Android Gradle Plugin 3.1.3.
>   Android SDK Build Tools 27.0.3 will be used.
>   To suppress this warning, remove "buildToolsVersion '26.0.1'" from your build.gradle file, as each version of the Android Gradle Plugin now has a default version of the build tools.
>   Could not find google-services.json while looking in [src/nullnull/debug, src/debug/nullnull, src/nullnull, src/debug, src/nullnullDebug]
>   registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
>   Could not find google-services.json while looking in [src/nullnull/release, src/release/nullnull, src/nullnull, src/release, src/nullnullRelease]
>   registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
>
> Configure project :react-native-google-analytics-bridge
>   WARNING: Configuration 'compile' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'implementation' and 'api'.
>   It will be removed at the end of 2018. For more information see: http://d.android.com/r/tools/update-dependency-configurations.html
>
> Configure project :react-native-radar
>   WARNING: Configuration 'compile' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'implementation' and 'api'.
>   It will be removed at the end of 2018. For more information see: http://d.android.com/r/tools/update-dependency-configurations.html
>
> Task :app:processDebugGoogleServices
>   Parsing json file: /Users/kyletreman/18F/courier_test_app/android/app/google-services.json
>
> /Users/kyletreman/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/appcompat-v7-23.0.1.aar/64df69838d7c555de168bdcf18f3be5c/res/values/values.xml:113:5-69: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/fontVariationSettings not found.
>
> /Users/kyletreman/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/appcompat-v7-23.0.1.aar/64df69838d7c555de168bdcf18f3be5c/res/values/values.xml:113:5-69: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/ttcIndex not found.
>
> error: failed linking references.
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong:
>     Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
>     Failed to process resources, see aapt output above for details.
> - Try:
>     Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
> - Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
>
> BUILD FAILED in 2s
>   50 actionable tasks: 3 executed, 47 up-to-date
>   Could not install the app on the device, read the error above for details.
>   Make sure you have an Android emulator running or a device connected and have
>   set up your Android development environment:
>   https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html

/android/app/build.gradle

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 27
buildToolsVersion "27.0.3"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.courier_test_app.app"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 27
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    ndk {
        abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
    }
}
splits {
    abi {
        reset()
        enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
        universalApk false  // If true, also generate a universal APK
        include "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
    }
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
    }
}
// applicationVariants are e.g. debug, release
applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    variant.outputs.each { output ->
        // For each separate APK per architecture, set a unique version code as described here:
        // http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/apk-splits
        def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a":1, "x86":2]
        def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
        if (abi != null) {  // null for the universal-debug, universal-release variants
            output.versionCodeOverride =
                    versionCodes.get(abi) * 1048576 + defaultConfig.versionCode
        }
    }
}
}

dependencies {
implementation(project(':react-native-firebase')) {
    transitive = false
}
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.0'
implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v13:27.1.1'
implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
implementation project(':react-native-radar')
implementation project(':react-native-google-analytics-bridge')
}

// Run this once to be able to run the application with BUCK
// puts all compile dependencies into folder libs for BUCK to use
task copyDownloadableDepsToLibs(type: Copy) {
from configurations.compile
into 'libs'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesPlugin.config.disableVersionCheck = true
```

/android/build.gradle

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
    google()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.0'
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    google()
    jcenter()
    maven {
        // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
        url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
    }
}
}

configurations.all {
resolutionStrategy {
    force 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.0'
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the error log I can see that `appcompat-v7-23.0.1` is still being used. So, it would probably help to update resolutionStrategy:

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy {
        force 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.0'
        force 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7-23.0.1'
    }
}
```

Also you need to place that resolution strategy block in your app/build.gradle

Answer (score 0):

**Fixed**

I was able to get help from someone familiar with the native side and he helped me sort out quite a few errors.

- implementation order matters, this was the order that worked for me

  ```
  implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
  implementation "com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1"
  implementation 'com.android.support:support-v13:27.1.1'
  implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1"
  implementation(project(':react-native-firebase'))
  implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
  implementation project(':react-native-radar')
  implementation project(':react-native-google-analytics-bridge')
  ```
- I need to move the configuration resolution strategies to the android/app/build.gradle file, mine were at the wrong level. I also had to alter versions of the support and appcompat packages. You can find dependencies via

  ```
  ./gradlew app:dependencies
  ```

  from the android folder. The issue was one of the dependencies was pulling a older version, which was fixed by using the following in the resolutionStrategies.

  ```
  force 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
  ```
- The next change that needed to be made was the following line in the MainApplication.java

  ```
     return BuildConfig.DEBUG;
  ```

  to this

  ```
     return <app_name>.BuildConfig.DEBUG;
  ```
- I also removed the enableaapt2=false

The last tip I can give is that naming matters, don't rename your app unless its absolutely necessary and make sure it changes across the Main java files and AndroidMainfest.xml.

**UPDATED**

- I realized my debugger was not connecting, it was because I removed some implementation packages that supported firebase, adding them back fixed the issue. Add the following below the firebase implementation.

  ```
  implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:15.0.1"
  implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1"
  ```

Answer (score 0):

put this code at the end of **android/build.gradle**
use your own numbers for the **compileSdkVersion**  and **buildToolsVersion**

```
subprojects {
    afterEvaluate {project ->
        if (project.hasProperty("android")) {
            android {
                compileSdkVersion 27
                buildToolsVersion "27.0.2"
            }
        }
    }
}
```